# Javascript jQuery: find array elements within a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I think my question is fairly straightforward but I'm not very experienced with Javascript.  What I am trying to do is pull the source code of a page and stick it all into a variable:

```
var sourcecode = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Then I have an array of terms that I want to search that variable for:

```
var array = ['Huskers','Redskins','Texans','Rockets'];
```

I would like to assign a 0 to any of the array elements that aren't found in the `sourcecode` variable and a 1 to any that are. So, when the search is complete each array element will be represented by a variable that will either equal 1 or 0. Can anyone please give me a hint as to how I should go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your problem? find the array element in `sourcecode` or something else?

Comment: I know how to search through the sourcecode for individual strings:    If (sourcecode.indexOf('Huskers')) != -1 {Huskers = 1}      but I'm thinking that if I do each search separately it will have to scroll through the entire string each time.

Comment: so this is the critical problem, you should add it to you post otherwise you only get answer about how to search them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit cryptic but does what you need:

```
var source = 'lorem hello foo bar world';
var words = ['hello','red','world','green'];

words = words.map(function(w){ return +!!~source.indexOf(w) });

console.log(words); //=> [1, 0, 1, 0]
```

`+!!~` casts a number of the boolean representation of the value returned by `indexOf`, same as:

```
return source.indexOf(w) == -1 ? 0 : 1;
```

But a bit shorter.

Note that `indexOf` matches strings within strings as well, if you want to match whole words you can use regex with word boundaries `\b`:

```
words = words.map(function(w) {
  return +new RegExp('\\b'+ w +'\\b','gi').test(source);
});
```

Comment: OK, I need to figure out what you are doing here exactly but I will try it out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find element in array you can use jquery $.inArray()

http://jsfiddle.net/hgHy4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var array = ['Huskers','Redskins','Texans','Rockets'];

    alert($.inArray('Redskins', array));


});
```

This will returns index number of element inside an array if it is found. If the element is not found it will return -1