# Using parent() in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension that blocks all porn results on all torrent search engine sites.

So I am trying to retrieve the name of the torrents and check them against the array of strings containing blocked (adult/porn) words that I created. If it matches the array word then it should set the **display of the parent element to none**. But parent() from jQuery doesn't seem to work around this in a for loop. This is the code that I am using.

```
// 'blockedWords' is the array.
// '$("dl dt")' contains the words that I am checking against strings from 
// the array 'blockedWords'.

for (var i = 0; i < $("dl dt").length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < blockedWords.length; j++) { 
    if($("dl dt")[i].innerText.indexOf(blockedWords[j]) > -1){
        $(this).parent().style.display= "none";       // 1st Method or
        $("dl dt")[i].parent().style.display= "none"; // 2nd Method
    }
  }
}

// 1st Method shows the error 'Cannot set property 'display' of undefined'
// 2nd Method shows the error '$(...)[i].parent is not a function'
// '$("dl dt")[i].parent().style.display' doesn't work but
// '$("dl dt").parent().style.display' doesn't work either
// '$("dl dt")[i].style.display' works perfectly without parent().
```

I have also tried 'parents()'.
Any help will be appreciated :). 
As a newbie, I am also open to any other suggestions or recommendations.
And I would be really grateful if you could explain your code as well :)

And by the way, can you believe there are more than 500 porn companies out there :o :P :D

Comment: The jQuery method should be `...parent().hide()`.

Comment: Thanks :) .hide() is much shorter alternative to the style.background. But it still doesn't solve the core problem.

Comment: *"But it still doesn't solve the core problem."* - Actually it *does* solve the core problem, because the core problem is that `.parent()` returns a jQuery object, and jQuery objects don't have a `.style` property. *"`$("dl dt").parent().style.display` works perfectly without the [i]"* - I don't see how it could, for the reason I just mentioned.

Comment: Sorry after using 'hide()' it still doesn't seem to be working. Error is still "$(...)[i].parent is not a function"

Comment: " '$("dl dt").parent().style.display works perfectly without the [i]' I don't see how it could, for the reason I just mentioned."
You are right, it doesn't work. sorry, my mistake. 
But 'hide()' still doesn't work either (at least not on its own).

Comment: From your previous comment you are trying `...[i].parent()` which won't work. The `[i]` part gets you a reference to the DOM element, and you can't call the jQuery `.parent()` method on that. Basically either use all jQuery methods, or use only non-jQuery properties to the right of any `[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have jQuery, you can avoid using nested for-loops using jQuery's `filter()` and JavaScript `reduce(s,v)`:

```
// Filter function removes elements that return a false/falsey value like 0
$("dl dt").filter(function() {

  // Save current element's innerText so we can use it within the reduce function
  var str = $(this).text();

  // Return sum of reduce function
  return blockedWords.reduce(function(s, v) {

    // For each item in blockedWords array, check whether it exists in the string. Add to total number of matches.
    return s + !!~str.indexOf(v);

  }, 0); // 0 = intial value of reduce function (number of matches)

}).parent().hide(); // Hide elements which pass through the filter function
```

Demo:

```js
var blockedWords = [
  'shit', 'fuck', 'sex'
];

$("dl dt").filter(function() {
  var str = $(this).text();
  return blockedWords.reduce(function(s, v) {
    return s + !!~str.indexOf(v);
  }, 0);
}).parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<dl><dt>this is shit</dt></dl>
<dl><dt>this is okay</dt></dl>
<dl><dt>fuck this</dt></dl>
<dl><dt>no problem</dt></dl>
<dl><dt>sex videos</dt></dl>
```

EDIT: I apologize for the earlier answer if you saw it, as it was incomplete. I have also added a snippet for demonstration purposes. For further explanation of the reduce algorithm, check [this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17057163/584192) (basically it converts the value of indexOf to either a 0 or 1, because indexOf returns -1 if not found, or another 0-indexed integer of the position if found).

Comment: I was banging my head against the 1st answer lol
Thanks, even though I rarely understand it, this one works perfectly :)

Comment: Thanks again for the comments and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's `parent` function returns a JQuery object with the parent element inside of it. If you want to access the element from this object you need to retrieve the element from the object using the bracket notation.

If you were to provide some HTML I would be able to test this and make sure it works, but here is some code that could get you pointed in the right direction to use mostly JQuery instead of relying on `for` loops with JavaScript.

## JQuery Rewrite

```
$("dl dt").each(function(index, element){
    if($.inArray(blockedWords,$(element).text()) > -1) {
        $(this).parent().css("display", "block");
        $(element).parent().css("display", "block");
    }
})
```

## The Answer To Your Specific Question

Change this:

```
$(this).parent().style.display= "none";       // 1st Method or
$("dl dt")[i].parent().style.display= "none"; // 2nd Method
```

to this:

```
$(this).parent()[0].style.display= "none";       // 1st Method or
$($("dl dt")[i]).parent()[0].style.display= "none"; // 2nd Method
```

optionally, you can instead use JQuery's `css` function like this:

```
$(this).parent().css("display", "none");       // 1st Method or
$($("dl dt")[i]).parent().css("display","none"); // 2nd Method
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to be working either. Error is still "$(...)[i].parent is not a function"

Comment: Oh right, thanks for the clarification. That means you're trying to use a JQuery function on a plain ol' DOM element. Wrap it in a JQuery selector. Updating my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: Somehow, 1st Method from both your answer still doesn't work, but no worries because 2nd method work like a charm. Thanks :)